# Apache Beam Metrics Counter giving incorrect count using SparkRunner

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I  am having source and target csv files with 10 million records with 250 columns. 
I am running an apache beam pipeline which joins all columns from source and target file.
When, I run this on spark cluster the pipeline executes correctly with no exceptions but, 
The join beam metrics counter returns double count when the following spark property is used.
-- executor-memory  "2g"
But, When I increase the excutor-memory to 11g then it returns the correct count.

I have tried following example,

```
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    final TupleTag<String> eventInfoTag = new TupleTag<>();
    final TupleTag<String> countryInfoTag = new TupleTag<>();



    PCollection<KV<String, String>> eventInfo =
    eventsTable.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractEventDataFn()));
    PCollection<KV<String, String>> countryInfo =
    countryCodes.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractCountryInfoFn()));



    PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> kvpCollection =
    KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(eventInfoTag, eventInfo)
        .and(countryInfoTag, countryInfo)
        .apply(CoGroupByKey.create());

    PCollection<KV<String, String>> finalResultCollection =
    kvpCollection.apply(
        "Process",
        ParDo.of(
            new DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, KV<String, String>>() {
              @ProcessElement
              public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                KV<String, CoGbkResult> e = c.element();
                String countryCode = e.getKey();
                String countryName = "none";
                countryName = e.getValue().getOnly(countryInfoTag);
                for (String eventInfo : c.element().getValue().getAll(eventInfoTag)) {
                    Metrics.counter("count", "errorcount").inc();
                  c.output(
                      KV.of(
                          countryCode,
                          "Country name: " + countryName + ", Event info: " + eventInfo));
                }
              }
            }));

    final PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
    MetricQueryResults metrics =
        result
            .metrics()
            .queryMetrics(
                MetricsFilter.builder()
                    .addNameFilter(MetricNameFilter.inNamespace("count"))
                    .build());
    Iterable<MetricResult<Long>> counters = metrics.getCounters();
    for (MetricResult<Long> counter : counters) {
        System.out.println("Hi  >> "+counter.getName().getName() + " : " + counter.getAttempted() + " " + counter.getCommittedOrNull());

    }
```

I need help with this.
Thank you

Comment: How many executors you are using?

Comment: --num-executors "6" --executor-cores "3"

Comment: Do you see the same incorrect results if you run your pipeline with `waitUntilFinish()`?

Comment: @Alexey Romanenko Yes. Observation - count doubles only when I dump the results to file but if I don't dump then counts are correct.

Comment: I suspect that it  could be related to different number of splits when you use different values for "executor-memory" but definitively it should not be a case. I suggest you to file a Jira issue about that to https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/ and/or ask on user@ mailing list to have more opinions

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyRomanenko,
Issue has been posted: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8838

Comment: @KunalGhosh Can you please add the snippet of the code you use to write to file.

Comment: @iemejia, added sample code below. If set captureError = true then beam metrics counter returns double count

Comment: @iemejia ,@Alexey Romanenko any workaround for the mentioned problem?

Comment: I'm also experiencing double counts on counters when running with spark. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration hadoopConf = new Configuration();
        hadoopConf.set("fs.defaultFS", args[13]);
        hadoopConf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
        hadoopConf.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
        final TupleTag<Row> sourceDataInfoTag = new TupleTag<Row>(){};
        final TupleTag<Row> targetDataInfoTag = new TupleTag<Row>(){};
        HadoopFileSystemOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(HadoopFileSystemOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
        options.setHdfsConfiguration(Collections.singletonList(hadoopConf));
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        PCollection<String> sourceData = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from(args[14]).withDelimiter("\n".getBytes()));
        PCollection<KV<Row, Row>> sourceDataRows = sourceData.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractFunction()));
        PCollection<String> targetData = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from(args[23]).withDelimiter("\n".getBytes()));
        PCollection<KV<Row, Row>> targetDataRows = targetData.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractFunction()));

        PCollection<KV<Row, CoGbkResult>> kvpCollection = KeyedPCollectionTuple 
                .of(sourceDataInfoTag, sourceDataRows.setCoder(KvCoder.of(RowCoder.of(SOURCE_JOIN_RECORD_TYPE),RowCoder.of(SOURCE_RECORD_TYPE)))) 
                .and(targetDataInfoTag, targetDataRows.setCoder(KvCoder.of(RowCoder.of(TARGET_JOIN_RECORD_TYPE),RowCoder.of(TARGET_RECORD_TYPE)))) 
                .apply(CoGroupByKey.<Row>create()); 

        PCollection<GenericRecord> finalResultCollections = kvpCollection.apply("process",ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Row, CoGbkResult>, GenericRecord>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
                KV<Row, CoGbkResult> element = context.element();
                Iterator<Row> srcIter = element.getValue().getAll(sourceDataInfoTag).iterator();
                Iterator<Row> trgIter = element.getValue().getAll(targetDataInfoTag).iterator();
                Metrics.counter("count", "count").inc();

                GenericRecordBuilder builder = new GenericRecordBuilder(SCHEMA);
                boolean done = false;
                boolean captureError = false;
                while (!done)
                {
                    // Some iterator data here.
                    .
                    .
                    builder.set(colName, data);
                    if(captureError){
                        GenericRecord record = builder.build();
                        context.output(record);
                    }
                }
            }
          })).setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, SCHEMA));

        finalResultCollections.apply("writeText",FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                .via(ParquetIO.sink(SCHEMA))
                .withSuffix(".parquet")
                .withPrefix("part")
                .to("hdfs://temp/"));


        final PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
        State state = result.waitUntilFinish();

        MetricQueryResults metrics =
            result
                .metrics()
                .queryMetrics(
                    MetricsFilter.builder()
                        .addNameFilter(MetricNameFilter.inNamespace("count"))
                        .build());
        Iterable<MetricResult<Long>> counters = metrics.getCounters();
        for (MetricResult<Long> counter : counters) {
            System.out.println("Count  >> "+counter.getName().getName() + " : " + counter.getAttempted() + " " + counter.getCommittedOrNull());

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you do `Metrics.counter("count", "errorcount")` you define the counter. But it is defined in a loop which is also in sort of a loop (processElement). You should define your counter as a field in the DoFn. Don't worry the DoFn is reused for processing the bundle. Such as: `private final Counter counter = Metrics.counter(MyClass.class, COUNTER_NAME);`

Also you showed only part of the code but I don't see `done` boolean set to true. But that is just out of curiosity.

And last but not least, you should try spark runner on master branch of Beam because there was a fix merged yesterday about metrics (metrics not reset when running multiple pipelines inside the same JVM). I don't know if it matches your use case but it's worth trying.